Connection between minimal norm subgradient and steepest descent
In my optimization course it was mentioned that for a non-smooth convex function, the subgradient with smallest norm provides the direction of steepest descent of the function, so if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ convex, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g \in \partial f(x)$ has minimal norm among all elements of the subgradient $\partial f(x)$, then $-g$ gives the direction of steepest descent.
Can someone please provide:

a reference for a proof or directly a proof?
geometric intuition?

thank you
